# Refresh parent view / mapStateToProps when dialog closes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have created a dialog that opens up on each row in a table, I can edit and send within that dialog info about a person. I close the dialog and need to refresh the page before I see it updated. What I need to do is update the parent component on dialog close.

I have put together a fluff free version of my parent component and how I am calling the data below -

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import PeopleEditDialog from './PeopleEditDialog';

class EnhancedTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            openPeopleEditDialog: false
        };

        this.handlePeopleEditDialog = this.handlePeopleEditDialog.bind(this);
    }

    handlePeopleEditDialog() {
        this.setState({
            openPeopleEditDialog: !this.state.openPeopleEditDialog
        });

    render() {
        const { openPeopleEditDialog } = this.state;
        const { loader, people, peopleListError } = this.props;

        return (
                <React.Fragment>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <div className="actions">
                                <Tooltip title="Edit">
                                    <IconButton aria-label="Edit" onClick={this.handlePeopleEditDialog}>
                                        <Edit />
                                    </IconButton>
                                </Tooltip>
                                <PeopleEditDialog
                                    open={this.state.openPeopleEditDialog}
                                    onClose={this.handlePeopleEditDialog}
                                    selected={selectedDialog}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </Toolbar>
                    <div className="flex-auto">
                        <div className="table-responsive-material">
                            <Table>
                                <TableBody>
                                    //Rows of people data
                                    {people}
                                </TableBody>

                            </Table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ peopleList }) => {
    const { loader, people, peopleListError, appliedFilters } = peopleList;
    return { loader, people, peopleListError, appliedFilters};
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {})(withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(EnhancedTable)));
```

peopleList does not update unless I refresh. I need to apply something to get the latest when I close the dialog:

```
<PeopleEditDialog
  open={this.state.openPeopleEditDialog}
  onClose={this.handlePeopleEditDialog}
  selected={selectedDialog}
 />
```

So how do I call the latest from mapStateToProps when the component closes so I get a refreshed list?

Comment: If you only needs a page reload you can try calling: `location.reload()`, after Dialog closes. I can't see in your examples what props are changing for this parent component, so why would it have to update unless a prop changes?

Comment: in the dialog, how do you update the info. if you update the state in peopleList.people your parent component should be updated

Comment: you will be rendering your table of rows with state . So you can update the state. Since state updates it will re render so no need to reload. So once you enter the details on dialog box you are updating in backend like calling an api . So if user refresh the page you will get the updated state.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS that is correct but this is not happening. User has to refresh page to get updated state from peopleList in my mapstatetoprops. My rows stay the same until refresh of page.